# android - instagram redirect uri doesn't return to my app

Tags: android, oauth, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to integrate instagram login (implicit login) into my application referring to [this tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/how-to-authenticate-on-android-using-social-logins/). I couldn't provide any redirect uri other than a valid url, so I gave my website url in the same.
Next I added the **schema** in launcher activity as "**http**" and **host** as "**www.mysite.com**" as mentioned in the tutorial.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
    <data android:host="www.mysite.com" />
</intent-filter>
```

The app launches the instagram login screen in web browser and authenticates and the access token is returned along with the redirect uri. At this time am expecting my app to take up this callback and launch, but this doesn't happen.

Below is the code used to get the token

```
private void signInWithInstagram() {
    final Uri.Builder uriBuilder = new Uri.Builder();
    uriBuilder.scheme("https")
            .authority("api.instagram.com")
            .appendPath("oauth")
            .appendPath("authorize")
            .appendQueryParameter("client_id", "MY_CLIENT_ID")
            .appendQueryParameter("redirect_uri", "MY_SITE_URL")
            .appendQueryParameter("response_type", "token");
    final Intent browser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriBuilder.build());
    startActivity(browser);
}
```

The MY_CLIENT_ID is the client from instagram developer account and MY_SITE_URL is the complete url including http://,
Can someone help me with this..

Comment: In which method you are receiving token and uri.? Post code for that.

Comment: @MuraliPrajapati Please see the question updated with the code used to get the token. Also I have given the uri in the instagram developer account which is the url of website

Comment: @MuraliPrajapati I have a LauncherActivity which displays a splash and then opens the Login Activity. I have placed the <intent-filter> for app linking inside LoginActivity's <activity>.

Comment: I tried with this command and it opened my app 
**adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "COMPLETE_SITE_URL" com.my.package**

But the app is not opening while I gave the url of my site in browser.  Do I need to add anything in the html page..???

Comment: are u calling `checkForInstagramData()` in onReume or in onStart()? if yes then it should work because this method is calling `handleSignInResult()`.

Comment: I called it in onResume(). But it didn't even resume the app to hit this function. I believe the website am redirecting into has to implement deep link in the same. Anyways I solved the instagram login by loading the web page in WebViewActivity instead of external browser and handled the redirection.  Thank for the support @MuraliPrajapati..